# Using Ajax to livesearch mySql and return results hidden by jquery toggle

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

How do i get the toggle to function in the search results? I am not sure what I need to do to get this to work.  Have a MySQL db, and am using AJAX to perform live search.  The search populates in table rows, and I want to hide certain rows unless user clicks "toggle".  The code to toggle and populate table works on a summary page, but I need it to work after search.

```
<?php
@session_start(); //start session
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="generic.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".seek").click(function(){
            $(".hide").toggle();
          });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".saButton").click(function(){
            $(".short").toggle();
          });
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".eaButton").click(function(){
            $(".essayans").toggle();
          });
        });
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlReq;
function processResponse(){
   if(xmlReq.readyState == 4){
       var place = document.getElementById("placeholder");
       place.innerHTML = xmlReq.responseText;
  }
}

   function loadResponse(){
      // create an instance of XMLHttpRequest 
      xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlReq.onreadystatechange = processResponse;

  xmlReq.open("POST", "findResults.php", true);

  //read value from search bar
  parameter = "keyword=" + encodeURI(document.forms["search"].keyword.value);

  //send headers
  xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 
              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameter.length);
  xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  xmlReq.send(parameter);
  return false;
   }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <?php include "generic_menu.php"; ?>
    <br><br>

    <nav>  <!--Menu for the Admin functions -->      
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="adminsOnly.php"><input type="button" 
                                        value="Admin Home"></a></li>
            <li><a href="surveys.php"><input type="button" 
                        value="Completed Surveys"></a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php"><input type="button" 
                                value="Search the Surveys"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="pageContent"> 
        <h1 class='pageTitle'>Search all Surveys Submitted</h1>

        <br><hr><br>

        <div class="qbox"> <!--Search Input Field -->   
            <?php
                session_regenerate_id();

                if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) OR !$_SESSION['authenticated'] == 1) { 
                    die ("ERROR: Unauthorized access!"); 
                } 
                else { 
                  echo  '

           <!--Search Input-->
         <form method="POST" name="search" action="" class="search">

    <h2>Search:<input type="text" name="keyword" onKeyUp="return loadResponse();"></h2>
        </form>';
                } 
            ?>     
        </div><br><!--END Search Input Field -->

        <!--Search RESULTS Field -->
        <div class="qbox"> 
        <h2>Search Results:  </h2><br><br>     
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
        <!--This is for the search results -->
        </div><br><!--END Search RESULTS Field -->
    </div><!--end page content -->
</body>
```

And this is the rest:

```
<html>
    <head>
 <title>Display Results</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".seek").click(function(){
            $(".hide").toggle();
          });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".saButton").click(function(){
            $(".short").toggle();
          });
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".eaButton").click(function(){
            $(".essayans").toggle();
          });
        });
        </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "limited_user", 
"this*password", "mcanazon");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . 
          mysqli_connect_error($conn);
  }
  else{
     //read keyword from database
     if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])){
        $search = "%".$_POST["keyword"]."%"; 

        // create prepared statement 
       if ($query = mysqli_prepare($conn, 
       "SELECT surveyTable.email, gender, ageGroup,
   dropdown, dropdown2, checkval, shortA, essay,
   response1, response2, response3, response4, system_date
   FROM surveyTable
   JOIN surveyTable2 ON surveyTable.id=surveyTable2.id
   WHERE concat(surveyTable.email, gender, ageGroup)  like ?")) {                  

       // bind parameters
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query, "s", $search);

        //run the query and keep results in $result variable
        mysqli_stmt_execute($query);

        // bind variables to prepared statement 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $email, $gender, $ageGroup, $dropdown, $dropdown2, $checkval, 
                $shortA, $essay, $response1, $response2, $response3, $response4, $system_date);

      // fetch values 
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {
            echo "

     <div class='qbox'><br><table border='1'><tr><th class='admintables'>Email</th><th class='admintables'>Date</th></tr>
                                                <tr><td>$email</td><td>$system_date</td></tr>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <table border='1'>
                <tr><th class='admintables'>Gender</th><th class='admintables'>Age Group</th></tr>
                <tr><td>$gender</td><td>$ageGroup</td></tr>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <table border='1'>
                <tr><th class='admintables'>This is a question with answer choices in drop-down format.</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Option:$dropdown</td></tr>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <table border='1'>
                <tr><th class='admintables'>This is another question with a drop-down format.</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Favorites: $dropdown2</td></tr>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <table border='1'>
                <tr><th class='admintables'>The following are checkboxes. You may choose more than one,<br>
                    but you must choose at least one:</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Boxes Checked: $checkval</td></tr>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <table border='1'>
                <caption class='admintables'><b>Please tell us how likely you agree with the following:<b><button class='seek'>Answer</button></caption>
                <tr class='hide' style='display:none'><th class='admintables'><p>Response for the 1st statement:</p></th><td><p>$response1</p></td></tr>
                <tr class='hide' style='display:none'><th class='admintables'><p>Response for the 2nd statement:</p></th><td><p>$response2</p></td></tr>
                <tr class='hide' style='display:none'><th class='admintables'><p>Response for the 3rd statement:</p></th><td><p>$response3</p></td></tr>
                <tr class='hide' style='display:none'><th class='admintables'><p>Response for the 4th statement:</p></th><td><p>$response4</p></td></tr>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <table border='1'>
                <caption class='admintables'><b>What do you think of this short answer question? <b>  <button class='saButton'>Answer</button></caption>
                <tr class='short' style='display:none'><td><p>$shortA </p></td></tr>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <table border='1'>
                <caption class='admintables'><b>In one paragraph, what do you <br>think of this paragraph answer question?<b>  <button class='eaButton'>Answer</button><caption class='caption'>
                <tr class='essayans' style='display:none'><td><p>$essay</p></td></tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                </div>
                <br><br><br>";
        }

        //free memory 
        mysqli_stmt_close ($query);


        } else 
          echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
      } else { 
          echo "Please enter a search term";
      }

     mysqli_close($conn);
 }
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much, I am extremely new to this (only used ajax once and never all these languages compiled together).

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: how do i get the toggle to function in the search results?